# How to create event in Cassandra for every inserts to NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I know we use NodeJS with Cassandra using [DataStax](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver), *but is it possible to create an event in Cassandra for every inserts that is done?* We can create [triggers in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html) but it will not update external system.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any event builtin the driver that could help you in this case.
You can create an event emitter:

```
var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

const query = 'INSERT INTO ...';
client.execute(query, params, { prepare: true }, function (err) {
  // ...
  emitter.emit('insert', err);
});
```

Then, you can listen to the `'insert'` event.

```
emitter.on('insert', function insertEventHandler(err) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: thanks jorgebg. please elaborate on listener, is it going to be a nodejs listerner and how to create it, what will be the dependency?

Comment: just to clarify inserts will not be done by using nodejs, that will be done by spark.

Comment: Cassandra does not emit an event per write made that the drivers can listen to. So, short answer: its not possible.